# Use an IronRuby wrapper method to get a block into C#

Tags: c#, ironruby

I'm using IronRuby and trying to come up with a seamless to pass a block to C#. This question is a follow on from [How to use an IronRuby block in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288290/how-to-use-an-ironruby-block-with-a-c-method) which indicates blocks cannot be passed between IronRuby and C#.

My subsequent question is as to whether there's a way to acheive the same goal using a Ruby wrapper method to make the block into a lambda or Proc object and pass it to C#?

Some code that's along the lines of what I'd like to be able to do is below. The code doesn't work but hopefully the intent is clear enough.

```
string scriptText =
    @"def BlockTest
     result = csharp.BlockTest somehow-pass-the-block ("hello")
     puts result
    end
    BlockTest { |arg| arg + 'world'}";

Console.WriteLine("Compiling IronRuby script.");
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scriptScope = scriptEngine.CreateScope();
scriptScope.SetVariable("csharp", new BlockTestClass());
scriptEngine.Execute(scriptText, scriptScope);
```

The C# BlockTest class is:

```
public class BlockTestClass
{
    public void BlockTest(Func<string, string> block)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(block("hello "));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A block is a mysterious thing that doesn't really exist in the CLR. Ruby does however have a `proc` which is analogous to CLR delegates.

For example, this should work fine:

C#:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void Run(Func<int, int> func) { ... }
}
```

Ruby:

```
proc = lambda { |i| i + 10 }
SomeClass.Run(proc)
```

There are several ways to create new procs (many people prefer `Proc.new`, but it doesn't quite work the same way as a C# function so I prefer lambda), but the key point is this:

`lambda` (and `Proc.new`) is a function - you pass the function a block, and it generates a new `Proc` object which wraps the block.

There is also a way of implicitly converting blocks to procs when they are passed to a function, using `&`.

Ruby:

```
def each
  yield 1
end
```

is the same as

```
def each(&block)
  block.call 1
end
```

The `&` takes the block which has been passed to the method (which would have otherwise been implicitly called by `yield`) and converts it into a `Proc`. Once it is a proc, you can pass it around, stick it in arrays, or pass it down to C#.

So, to call your C# method, you have two options:

1. Create a wrapper method which takes the block, and uses `&` to convert it to a proc. You can then call the underlying C# method with this proc
2. Use `lambda` or `Proc.new` in ruby to create a proc directly, and pass it to the C# method.

Examples:

C# Code (common):

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void Print(Func<int, int> converter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1: {0}", converter(1));
    }
}
```

Ruby Code 1 (wrapper):

```
class MyClass
  class << self # this is only needed to alias class (static) methods, not for instance methods
    alias_method :original_print, :print
  end

  def self.print(&block)
    original_print block
  end
end

MyClass.print {|i| i * 10}
```

Ruby Code 2 (direct):

```
MyClass.print lambda{|i| i * 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the complete answer, but you'll probably get farther if you call `block.to_proc` to convert it into a callable Proc object.

Answer (score 0):

I had no success with `Func<>`-Delegates and Blocks or Procs. Lazily, I used the `Proc`-Class in C# and called it from Ruby with `block.to_proc`. In C# you can then use `Proc.Call` and cast your result.

It's been a while so maybe this is out-dated.